# strange behavior when checking sat Z3

Tags: z3, z3py

Can somebody see what I am doing wrong.... I am using the for all quantifier to create this two lines :

```
(assert(forall((t Task)) (not (mustPrecede t t))))
(assert(forall((t1 Task)(t2 Task)(t3 Task)) (implies (and (mustPrecede t1 t2)(mustPrecede t2 t3)) (mustPrecede t1 t3))))
```

this is the code..

```
    Sort User = ctx.mkUninterpretedSort("User");
    Sort Task = ctx.mkUninterpretedSort("Task");
    //function declaration
    FuncDecl assignUser = ctx.mkFuncDecl("assignUser", Task, User);
    FuncDecl TaskUser = ctx.mkFuncDecl("TaskUser", new Sort[] { Task, User }, ctx.mkBoolSort());
    FuncDecl mustPrecede = ctx.mkFuncDecl("mustPrecede", new Sort[]{Task,Task}, ctx.mkBoolSort());

    //task for using in quatifiers
    Expr task = ctx.mkConst("t",Task);
    Expr user = ctx.mkConst("u",User);

    // creating (assert(forall((t Task)) (not (mustPrecede t t))))
    //just one task is needed
    Sort[] Tasks = new Sort[1];
    Tasks[0] = Task;
    //setting the name for the task
    Symbol[] namess = new Symbol[1];
    namess[0] =  ctx.mkSymbol("t");
    //Creating a map between mustPrecede and  its two parameters
    Expr mtt = ctx.mkApp(mustPrecede, task,task);
    //acreating not
    Expr body = ctx.mkNot((BoolExpr)mtt);

    Expr mustPrecedett = ctx.mkForall(Tasks, namess, body, 1, null, null,
            ctx.mkSymbol("Q1"), ctx.mkSymbol("skid1"));


    System.out.println("Quantifier mustPrecedett: " + mustPrecedett.toString());

    //creating (assert(forall((t1 Task)(t2 Task)(t3 Task)) (implies (and (mustPrecede t1 t2)(mustPrecede t2 t3)) (mustPrecede t1 t3))))

    //tree taks will be neede
    Sort[] tTask = new Sort[3];
    tTask[0] =Task;
    tTask[1] =Task;
    tTask[2] =Task;

    //setting the names for the tasks
    Symbol[] Tnames = new Symbol[3];
    Tnames[0] =  ctx.mkSymbol("t1");
    Tnames[1] =  ctx.mkSymbol("t2");
    Tnames[2] =  ctx.mkSymbol("t3");

    //creating tree diferent tasks for the relations
    Expr t1 = ctx.mkConst("t1",Task);
    Expr t2 = ctx.mkConst("t2",Task);
    Expr t3 = ctx.mkConst("t3",Task);
    //creating mappins
    Expr mt1t2 = ctx.mkApp(mustPrecede, t1,t2);
    Expr mt2t3 = ctx.mkApp(mustPrecede, t2,t3);
    Expr mt1t3 = ctx.mkApp(mustPrecede, t1,t3);
    //Creating the relation between them        
    Expr tbody2= ctx.mkImplies(ctx.mkAnd((BoolExpr)mt1t2,(BoolExpr) mt2t3), (BoolExpr) mt1t3);  
    //building quatifier
    Expr tra = ctx.mkForall(tTask, Tnames, tbody2, 1, null, null,ctx.mkSymbol("Q1"), ctx.mkSymbol("skid1"));
```

Then I am adding both to the solver as follows:

```
    // creating (assert(forall((t Task)) (not (mustPrecede t t))))
    solver.add(ctx.mkForall(Tasks, namess, body, 1, null, null,ctx.mkSymbol("Q1"), ctx.mkSymbol("skid1")));
    //creating (assert(forall((t1 Task)(t2 Task)(t3 Task)) (implies (and (mustPrecede t1 t2)(mustPrecede t2 t3)) (mustPrecede t1 t3))))
    solver.add(ctx.mkForall(tTask, Tnames, tbody2, 1, null, null,ctx.mkSymbol("Q1"), ctx.mkSymbol("skid1")));
```

but when asserting

```
    //T2 ; T4 ;(; T12 ; T13 ;AND ; T14 ; T15;) ; T10; T11
    Expr T2 = ctx.mkConst("t2", Task);
    Expr T3 = ctx.mkConst("t3", Task);

    Expr mt = ctx.mkApp(mustPrecede, T2,T3);
    Expr mts = ctx.mkApp(mustPrecede, T3,T2);



    solver.add(ctx.mkAnd((BoolExpr)mt,(BoolExpr)mts));
```

The sat solver is reporting SAT.. but this si not possible since mustePrecede is irreflexive according to my previous definitions with quantifiers.. Can somebody see what I am missing or why the sat solver is not considering the "constraints" I added with the foralls??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to construct quantified expressions in Z3, one is by using named constants, the other is by de-Brujin indexed variables. The code posted here mixes these two and thus creates expressions that *look* right, when they aren't.

The following parts:

```
Sort[] tTask = ...
Symbol[] Tnames = ...
...
Expr t1 = ctx.mkConst("t1",Task);
...
Expr mt1t2 = ctx.mkApp(mustPrecede, t1,t2);
...
Expr tra = ctx.mkForall(tTask, Tnames, ...
```

construct the body of the quantifier from constants ("t1" etc), but the call to `ctx.mkForall` requires de-Brujin indexed variables (the indexes are implicit and `tTask` and `tnames` assigns names and sorts to them). For this to work, the body needs to be constructed using indexed variables, which are generated by calls to `ctx.mkBound(...)`.
Conversely, if constant expressions are preferred, the quantifier could be constructed by a call to `ctx.mkForall(Expr[] boundConstants, ...` where the first argument is an array of constant expressions like `new Expr[] { t1, t2, t3 }`.

The best way to see why the code doesn't work is when the symbols in `Tnames` are assigned different names. It is then plain to see from in output that there is a mismatch between those variables. For example, changing the code to

```
....
Expr t1 = ctx.mkConst("x",Task);
Expr t2 = ctx.mkConst("y",Task);
Expr t3 = ctx.mkConst("z",Task);
....
```

changes the first quantifier to

```
(forall ((x Task) (y Task) (z Task)) (not (mustPrecede t t)))
```

Comment: I did the changes and now everything works perfectly!! thanks a lot for your help